# Android - How do you scroll to a point within a layout before the layout loads?

Tags: android

I have limited knowledge with android programming, and am currently facing an issue i have Googled to no success.

Within my app i have multiple intents. When i click a button, it will load the new intent as it should. My problem is that i have a horizontal scrollview displaying across the bottom of my screen as my menu. When a user clicks a button it is meant to load the new intent and scroll to the current position on the scroll menu.

The issue however is that my menu bar is loaded in each layout. When the new intent layout loads, the horizontal scroll across the bottom will always jump to the start before scrolling to the current page icon.

How would you scroll from the previous pages icon in the menu, to the new page icon? I have made images but am currently unable to post them. Sorry if the question sounds hard to understand.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the visibility of all the buttons to invisible and then changing them to visible after you scroll to the right one?

Comment: I did try that, however i wasn't able to figure out how to set it to invisible before loading the layout for display. So it would jump and then flick.

Comment: Just set it to invisible in the XML layout file and then to visible in the code.